# shell script to run cucumber files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I have around 50 feature files and I want the tester team to run them. I don't want them to run all the files at once and also don't want them to get in the prerequisites for running cucumber ie..`bundle install ...rake db:migrate...service postgresql start...... etc`

I want to make a shellscript file so that they can execute it, select the option which file to run (all or other individual file) and then the script would execute the prerequisites and execute the file and output the log to specified folder. I want to make a sh file.

Comment: What exactly the problem to write all your command into text file with '.sh' extension and executable mode?

Comment: i am new to shell scripts...hencefinding it challenging to write an interactive script.i have coded simple ones,but this one is a bit tricky.

Comment: You could also try using capistrano to "deploy" the application to your testers' machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course I don't know your development environment or exactly what commands you need to execute to get your tests running, but here's a sample shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

bundle install
rake db:migrate
rake db:test:prepare
rake cucumber "$@"
```

Execute the script like this:

```
./script_name.sh
```

With arguments:

```
./script_name.sh features/registration.feature
```

The `"$@"` part will pass any arguments like features/registration.feature to `rake cucumber`.

Comment: when i exe this ,i get some minor error  as      <code>                                                      [root@www_trunk]# sh milind.sh
Could not find task "install\r".
rake aborted!
'on't know how to build task 'db:migrate

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
'on't know how to build task 'db:test:prepare

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
<code>

Comment: You have to set permission to execute the script. For example `chmod 755 milind.sh`.

Comment: thanks but im still getting this error Could not find task "install\r". rake aborted!
'on't know how to build task 'db:migrate                                                           rake aborted!
'on't know how to build task 'db:test:prepare